# Can MS Excel use non-printable characters as field separators in CSV files? If so, how?

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

I've just discovered that many of the character encodings have [non-printable characters designed to separate different pieces of information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter#ASCII_delimited_text), e.g., ASCII character 31 is the "unit separator".  It seems that if I could use one of these characters as the separator in a "comma/character separated value" (CSV), I could avoid problems in escaping the values that could occur in text, e.g., commas.

Is it possible to make MS Excel (2007) use the "unit separator" instead of a comma?  If so, how can I do that?

Edit:

How can I enter the non-printable character?  If I try searching for Unicode "001F" in the Character Map, I get a high-lighted blank box, and a "No Character Available" message, as shown below:

[image]

I'd rather not install a special program just to generate the non-printable character, but I can if I have to.

Comment: try [Export or save Excel files with other delimiters](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/21456/export-or-save-excel-files-with-pipe-or-other-delimiters-instead-of-commas/)

Comment: How can I input a non-printable character?

Comment: Try coping a non-printable character from [Character Map](http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/accents/charmap.html) and pasting it into the `List Separator` box from link above

Comment: +1 for pointer to Character Map.  I've edited my post to reflect my failed use of Character Map.

Comment: Ascii Decimal 31 appear as a triangle pointing down for me: ▼

Comment: Can use a macro.  I have open office only . If you want i can make one and put it on my github so others can review its safe before using it, wont be more than 10 lines of code to take a range, write to a text file with any ascii char code as field and record (row) separators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick test verifies that @bobSmith1432 has a workable solution.

I used Notepad++ to generate ASCII character 31 and copy it in order to paste into the `List separator:` field.

In Windows 7, go to `Control Panel` and select `Region and Language`. On the `Format` tab click the `Additional settings...` button. This will bring up the `Customize Format` window. Here, change the comma in the `List separator:` field to your ASCII character 31 by pasting it from some other source.

You should probably change this back to a comma immediately after saving your spreadsheet as a CSV.

**Edit:** As an alternative to Notepad++, you can use regular old notepad. With number lock ON, open Notepad, hold down the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key and hit <kbd>0</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> on the number pad. Then release the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to select the non-printing character and copy it. You can then paste the character into the `Customize Format` window.

Comment: Thanks, Dane!  +1 for the pointer to "Customize Format".  I'd prefer to avoid doing a global replacement of the list separator.  Knowing me, I'd forget to revert the temporary non-printable value to a more conventional one.  Also, I'd prefer a solution that didn't involve installing additional software.  Of course, I'll take what I can get.

Comment: I've added an explanation for how to do it with vanilla Notepad. If there is a built-in way to change the CSV separator, I'd love to hear about it. This method is definitely not something I'd be happy to perform, especially with any regularity.

Comment: Wow.  That actually worked!  +1 for the Notepad explanation.

Comment: thanks. It worked for me using `Alt+031` directly in Region contol panel->Advanced->List separator. You see nothing but it works.

Answer (score 1):

I just thought of another way to do this. Create an additional worksheet within the spreadsheet you want to export. In `A1` of the new worksheet, place the following formula:

`=CONCATENATE(Sheet1!A1,CHAR(31),Sheet1!B1,CHAR(31),Sheet1!C1)`

Change `Sheet1` to be the name of the worksheet you want to export as CSV. Repeat the pattern for additional columns. The above formula grabs columns `A`, `B`, and `C`. For `D` as well, use the following:

`=CONCATENATE(Sheet1!A1,CHAR(31),Sheet1!B1,CHAR(31),Sheet1!C1,CHAR(31),Sheet1!D1)`

Hopefully you can see the pattern there. Copy this cell down for as many rows as you want. `CHAR(31)` is inserting the ASCII character you want.

Then, save as CSV, and only export this new sheet. Because you only have a single column, no commas or other separators will be added.

Answer (score 0):

Simpler yet:

Open the file in Notepad. 
Select the delimiter character. 
Press ctrl-C to copy to clipboard. 
Now open the file in Excel. 
Select "My file has delimiters". 
Click Next. 
Paste the delimiter character where prompted.